# Apollo-Server, can I change AWSDateTime to Date when serving locally?

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo-server

I have a graphql server on AWS AppSync that I'm trying to create a local Apollo-Server for to test locally. When I start the local server on a test file (localSchema.ts) I get the error: `Unknown type "AWSDateTime".` the date needs to be AWSDateTime for AppSync, is there a way to conditionally make that a Date type?
Here is the schema:

````
const typeDefs = gql`
  directive @aws_api_key on OBJECT
  directive @aws_cognito_user_pools on OBJECT
  directive @aws_api_key on FIELD_DEFINITION
  directive @aws_cognito_user_pools on FIELD_DEFINITION

  enum DeliveryMethodEnum {
    PRINT_BACK
    DELIVERY
    DELIVERY_WITH_REPORTS
    PICKUP
  }

  enum CompanyStatusEnum {
    ON_BOARDING
    ACTIVE
    TERMINATED
    FROZEN
    NSF
    PENDING_1ST_PAYROLL
    TEST
  }

  type Company @aws_api_key @aws_cognito_user_pools {
    id: Int!
    companyNo: String
    legalName: String
    dba: String
    fein: String
    companyStatus: CompanyStatusEnum
    companyType: String
    logoKey: String
    hubspotId: String
    productTourStarted: Boolean
    productTourDashboardStarted: Boolean
    hasWatchedDemoVideo: Boolean
    groupId: Int
    createdBy: String
    createdAt: AWSDateTime
    updatedBy: String
    updatedAt: AWSDateTime
  }

  type CompanySingleResponse @aws_api_key @aws_cognito_user_pools {
    resCode: Int!
    resMessage: String
    data: Company
  }

  type Query {
    getCompanyById(id: ID): CompanySingleResponse
      @aws_api_key
      @aws_cognito_user_pools
  }
`;

export default typeDefs;```
````

Answer (score 1):

It seems like I need to define it with `scalar AWSDateTime`

Comment: Where is this configured?

Comment: If you mean defining the scalar I was able to do it in the .graphql file